# Strange links on my Wordpress home page, How to remove them?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have strange links on the main page. I don't know if it's spam or hack.

I have reviewed the plugins, as I do not have many I do not think that is a problem. Any ideas?

This is how it comes out. rare red links:

[image]

Comment: You've been hacked. The most likely place for this is one of the main php files in the directory. Check each one for unrecognizable code. Once it's cleaned up (good luck), then update your Wordpress and all plugins, and check for any security holes. You may need to talk to your host about it.

Comment: first of all: change all of the pages passwords and check for users you don't know.

Comment: There is only one administrator user, and it is mine